# Shape is not aligned in Gradient Descent

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to get the gradient descent by calculating values in the function. And getting an error in my code

```
def gradient_descent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters):
m = len(y)
cost_history = np.zeros(num_iters)
theta_history = np.zeros((num_iters,2))

for i in range(num_iters):
    prediction = np.reshape(np.dot(np.transpose(theta), X),97)
    theta = theta -(1/m)*alpha*( X.T.dot((prediction - y)))
    theta_history[i,:] =theta.T
    J_history[i]  = cal_cost(theta,X,y)

return theta, J_history


"""Args
----
X (numpy mxn array) - The example inputs, first column is expected
   to be all 1's.
y (numpy m array) - A vector of the correct outputs of length m
theta (numpy nx1 array) - An array of the set of theta parameters
   to evaluate
alpha (float) - The learning rate to use for the iterative gradient
   descent
num_iters (int) - The number of gradient descent iterations to perform

Returns
-------
theta (numpy nx1 array) - The final theta parameters discovered after
    out gradient descent.
J_history (numpy num_itersx1 array) - A history of the calculated
    cost for each iteration of our descent.
"""
```

Following are the parameters that I have passed to the function and variables

```
theta = np.zeros( (2, 1) )
iterations = 1500;
alpha = 0.01
theta, J = gradient_descent(X, y, theta, alpha, iterations)
```

The error message is:

> ValueError: shapes (97,2) and (97,) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 97 (dim 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly where you're getting the ValueError, but the ndarray with the shape (97,) needs to have `np.expand_dims` ran on it, like so:

`np.expand_dims(vector, axis=-1)`

This will make the vector have the shape (97,1), and thus it should be aligned/able to be broadcasted.

Comment: This is the line where I am getting an error  :                                                  
 prediction = np.reshape(np.dot(np.transpose(theta), X),97)